# Water got into internal AC vent, now it's blowing only warm air

Tags: ac, mitsubishi, water-leak

I have a Mitsubishi Galant Fortis 2008. Fooling around and some water splashed got into the internal AC vent nearest to the radio while driving. Shortly after, I felt a small mist of water on my feet the lights started flickering on the radio and the AC shut off, the knobs are now unresponsive and if I turn the vehicle on, it's barely blowing some low warm air and the lights are still flickering.

After stopping to inspect, the floor of the passenger side was wet as well. I have a little knowledge of where certain things are, I removed the glove compartment on the passenger side and the fuses and wires there showed no signs of being wet. What could have caused this electrical fault and did I damage anything that will potentially be costly to replace?

A friend stopped by with his scan tool and the only error code I'm getting is **B1000**.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess I got a bit lucky here, I got up this morning to go get it looked at and it was working, I guess the water dried up overnight; I also let it run on max heat for a couple minutes just in case. Now working as expected and back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a short somewhere because of the water. According to the description of the b1000 code located [here](http://www.diagnostictrouble.com/obdii-code/b1000):

**Symptoms of a B1000 diagnostic trouble code may include:**

- Faulty or damaged wiring

An easy way to dry out the car/possibly dry whatever electrical you got wet would be to use some [DampRid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029EGUNG). That might help mitigate your issue.